# Drawer in react / antd does not open on the right side, just below all components

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, antd, drawer

I want that when pressing on my search button, open a menu on the right side, but it is not obeying, it opens below the table

```
<div className='container-fluid'>
  <Drawer
    title="Teste"
    closable={true}
    onClose={this.onClose}
    visible={this.state.displayDiv}
  >
    <p>Some contents...</p>
    <p>Some contents...</p>
    <p>Some contents...</p>
  </Drawer>
  <div className='row' style={{ marginLeft: 30 }}>
    <button class='btn btn-outline-success' type='button' onClick={this.changeDiv} style={{ marginLeft: 20, height: 40 }}>
      Pesquisar
    </button>
  </div>

  <table>
    {...}
  </table>
</div>
```

I'm using the bootstrap for style and antd as components

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. While Investigating I found out that I haven't imported my antd css into my index.css file.

here is my index.css file:

```
@import '~antd/dist/antd.css';


body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
    monospace;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To the `<Drawer>`  component in *antd* you can pass such parameter as `placement`.

`placement` accept one of those string parameter: `top | right | bottom | left`.

In your case you need to add following line to your Drawer component: `placement={'right'}`.

As well you might need to open your drawer inside a parent component, then you need to pass `getContainer={false}`.

You can see official antd example with answer to your question [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/peswdm)

Documentation and more examples are [here](https://ant.design/components/drawer/)